Docx Module not populating information Correctly?
I am having an issue with getting specifically the inputs of 'company name', 'manager name', and 'position' to populate correctly. When I run the code, Word gives me a notification that "WordPad does not support all of the features of this document's format" and then the names and position populate as <built-in method title of str object at 0x00000140A4DA91D0\>.
It should instead replace the 'company name', 'manager name', and 'position' with their respective inputs.
import docx
count = 1

def Paragraph(text, font, pt_size):
    p = doc.add_paragraph()

    p.paragraph_format.line_spacing = 1
    p.paragraph_format.space_after = 0

    run = p.add_run(text)
    run.font.name = font
    run.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(pt_size)

def Content(manager_name, position):
    def Para_Open(pos):
        open = f'for {pos}'
        return open

    p = doc.add_paragraph()
    run = p.add_run(f"Dear {manager_name},\n")
    run.font.name = 'Arial'
    run.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(11)
    doc.add_paragraph()

    Paragraph(Para_Open(position), 'Arial', 11)
    doc.add_paragraph()

def Cover_Letter(company_name, manager_name, position):
    run = p.add_run(manager_name)
    run.font.name = 'Arial'
    run.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(11)

    run = p.add_run(company_name)
    run.font.name = 'Arial'
    run.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(11)

    Content(manager_name, position)

    #Save the document
    doc.save(f"{count} Cover Letter.docx")


print("Please enter the company's name:")
comp_name = str(input().title)

print("Please enter Hiring Manager's name (leave blank if none):")
mngr_name = str(input().title)
if mngr_name == '':
    mngr_name = 'Hiring Manager'

print("Please enter the position:")
position = str(input().title)

Cover_Letter(comp_name, mngr_name, position)

I've sifted through some of the documentation on the Docx module, but wasn't able to identify a possible fix. The rest of the program works great, but it seems to have an issue with the f-strings which allow me to have the dynamic variables included. I've attached a picture for reference on what the output is as well.
Str Obj Issue
I feel like the issue is likely in either my calling of Para_Open() or in my definition of Para_Open(), though I'm not sure how to fix it.
